# Incorrect syntax near '=' dynamic sql

Tags: sql-server

I'm thinking I have another basic issue with quotes or where clauses in my dynamic sql, but I can't seem to get this code to work. I am trying to output a variable from sp_executesql and keep getting the following error `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near '='.`

All the non-showing parameters have been declared earlier in the statement (I can list them if that is helpful). Please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong! Thank you

```
DECLARE @SqlCommand2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
, @LastDate DATETIME 

SET @SqlCommand2= N'SELECT MAX('+QUOTENAME(@DateField)+')=@LDate 
                FROM '+QUOTENAME(@table)+'
                WHERE PgmAdmissionKey = @PgmAdmissionKey'

EXEC sp_executesql @SqlCommand2, N'@DateField VARCHAR(100), @table VARCHAR(100), @PgmAdmissionKey INT, @LDate DATETIME OUTPUT', @DateField=@DateField, @Table=@table, @PgmAdmissionKey=@PgmAdmissionKey, @LDate=@LastDate OUTPUT
```

Comment: Your SQL doesn't make sense. It's like saying: select FieldName=Value From Table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *probably* meant:

```
SELECT @LDate = MAX('+QUOTENAME(@DateField)+')
```

Comment: smh, I didn't realize the order mattered :(